# Array.splice não funciona como esperado

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo:

```
var frutas = ["goiaba", "manga", "laranja", "abacate"];
frutas.splice(1, 1);
```

Esse código, ao invés de remover 1 item a partir do segundo índice do meu array (1), apenas retorna o item que eu quero excluir, que neste caso é "laranja";

Ou seja, ao invés de retornar `["goiaba", "manga", "abacate"]` - ele retorna `["laranja"]`;

Pelo que entendi no que li/pesquisei à respeito, o `Array.prototype.splice()` serve para fazer o que estou tentando ai. Estou certo? Se sim, por que esse comportamento do método `splice`?

OBS: navegador Google Chrome versão 60

Comment: Pela [documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Retorno) sobre o retorno da função: "*Uma lista contendo os elementos removidos.*". Parece que você entendeu errado.

Comment: Faz isso aí que o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse e remove o elemento do array. Se você ver o conteúdo de seu array frutas ele será `["goiaba", "laranja", "abacate"]` como esperado.

Comment: Agora entendi... Eu achei que o splice retornava um novo Array sem o item a ser removido. 
Muito obrigado aos dois.

Comment: Devo remover a questão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `splice` é um método de uso geral para inserir elementos em um array, remover elementos de um array, ou efetuar as duas operações ao mesmo tempo.

O primeiro argumento do `splice` especifica a posição do array em que a inserção ou exclusão deve começar.

O segundo argumento especifica o nº de elementos que devem ser excluídos.

Os dois primeiros argumentos de `splice` especificam quais elementos do array devem ser excluídos. Esses argumentos podem ser seguidos por qualquer numero de argumentos adicionais, especificando os elementos a serem inseridos no array, começando na posição especificada pelo primeiro argumento.

Veja como funciona:

```js
var frutas = ["goiaba", "manga", "laranja", "abacate"];
//remove 1 elemento posição 1 (remove manga) 
var frutasRemovida = frutas.splice(1, 1);

var nomes = ["Leo", "inova pixel", "Anderson Carlos Woss", "fernandoandrade", "mengano",  "fulano", "ciclano", "beltrano", "sicrano"];
//remove 3 elementos começando da posição 2 (remove Anderson Carlos Woss, fernandoandrade e mengano) 
var nomesRemovidos = nomes.splice(2, 3);

console.log(frutas);

console.log(frutasRemovida);

console.log(nomes);

console.log(nomesRemovidos);
```

Agora repare esse exemplo:

```js
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//remove 1 elemento começando da posição 3 e inclui os elementos "a" "b" a começando da posição 3 
var add = numeros.splice(3,1,"a","b");

console.log(numeros);
console.log(add);
```

E mais esse

```js
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var add = numeros.splice(2,2,"a","b","c","[123asd]");

console.log(numeros);
console.log(add);
```

Comment: Fiquei confuso com sua resposta.

Comment: @durtto, vai entender melhor se estudar os fundamentos https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice