# O splice retira um objeto do array?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Tenho uma dúvida em JavaScript.

Quando eu dou um splice em um array, ele retira o quê?

Por exemplo, eu tenho um array com vários objetos dentro, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
lixo: [
  {"nome": "garrafa pet", "tipo": "reciclável", "cod": 12, "armazenavel": false},
  {"nome": "lata de ref.", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 22, "armazenavel": true},
  {"nome": "lapis de cor", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 107, "armazenavel": false},
],
```

Se eu fizer isso aqui:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= lixo.lenght; i++){
  if(lixo[i].nome == "lata de ref."{
     let coleta = lixo.splice(i, 1)
  }
}
```

Nesse caso acima, depois que eu rodei o for e entrou no if, a variável Coleta vai receber o quê? por acaso ele recebe outro array com o objeto da lata de ref. dentro? ou Coleta só vai ser um objeto da lata de ref.?

Se for um array que coleta estiver recebendo, como eu faço pra ele armazenar apenas o objeto da lata de ref.? Tipo assim, eu não quero que ele receba um array de um único objeto da lata de ref.. No caso, eu quero que coleta recebe apenas o objeto extraído do array.

Alguém sabe como fazer pra coleta receber apenas um objeto e não um array com um objeto dentro?

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Relacionada: [Array.splice não funciona como esperado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238518/array-splice-n%C3%A3o-funciona-como-esperado)

Comment: Mas se o seu objetivo é ficar com o objeto na posição porque utiliza `splice` ? Porque não faz apenas `let coleta = lixo[i];` ?

Answer (score -1):

Além de retirar, o `.splice()` irá criar outra array com o objeto, no seu caso, o que foi encontrado no `if`. Logo, `coleta` seria uma array como:

```
coleta = 
[0]: {"nome": "lata de ref.", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 22, "armazenavel": true}
```

Veja que cria uma array com um índice `[0]` com um objeto dentro.

Você pode extrair esse objeto da array pegando o índice `[0]`:

```
coleta[0]
```

Só que, se você usar `let coleta` dentro do `if`, a variável `coleta` não vai ser acessível em lugar nenhum fora do `if`, por causa do escopo de bloco do `let`. Então declare o `let coleta` fora do `if` para que tenha um escopo mais amplo onde você pode usá-la:

```js
const lixo = [
  {"nome": "garrafa pet", "tipo": "reciclável", "cod": 12, "armazenavel": false},
  {"nome": "lata de ref.", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 22, "armazenavel": true},
  {"nome": "lapis de cor", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 107, "armazenavel": false},
]

let coleta;

for(let i = 0; i < lixo.length; i++){
  if(lixo[i].nome == "lata de ref."){
     coleta = lixo.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

coleta = coleta[0];
console.log("coleta: ",coleta);
```

Bem como o objeto encontrado será também retirado da array original `lixo`:

```js
const lixo = [
  {"nome": "garrafa pet", "tipo": "reciclável", "cod": 12, "armazenavel": false},
  {"nome": "lata de ref.", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 22, "armazenavel": true},
  {"nome": "lapis de cor", "tipo": "não reciclável", "cod": 107, "armazenavel": false},
]

let coleta;

for(let i = 0; i < lixo.length; i++){
  if(lixo[i].nome == "lata de ref."){
     coleta = lixo.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

coleta = coleta[0];
console.log("lixo: ", lixo);
```